# CORS HEADERS present only on preflight or every request

Tags: html, cors

It is not clear to me if **CORS** headers (Access-Control-Allow-Origin, etc) should be present only on the **preflight request** (OPTIONS method) or also in the resource's headers (which I'm trying to **POST** using XHR)

I'm asking this because I installed a python plugin which handles cors by only adding the **CORS** headers to the **OPTIONS** method (preflight), but not to the requested resource, this approach is NOT solving the cors issue on chrome and firefox, returning messages like

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading
>   the remote resource at [URL]. This can be fixed by
>   moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.

Edit:

I also found more info on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/ , which says:

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin (required) - This header must be included
>   in all valid CORS responses; omitting the header will cause the CORS
>   request to fail. The value of the header can either echo the Origin
>   request header (as in the example above), or be a '*' to allow
>   requests from any origin. If you’d like any site to be able to access
>   your data, using '*' is fine. But if you’d like finer control over who
>   can access your data, use an actual value in the header.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They must be present on both responses.

Step 3 of [the preflight rules](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#cross-origin-request-with-preflight-0) requires that the browser follows the normal [make a request steps](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#make-a-request-steps).

Comment: That seems right, I also found some info on http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Answer (score 8):

The Access-Control-Allow-Origin header MUST appear on the response to BOTH the preflight OPTIONS and the GET request itself. If Access-Control-Allow-Credentials appears in the preflight OPTIONS response, it must also appear in the response to the GET. Likewise with the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header.

The Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Access-Control-Allow-Methods and Access-Control-Max-Age response headers are ONLY needed in the OPTIONS response, and are ignored if they are returned in the response to the main fetch.

See https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-responses, which is THE CORS spec, and supersedes the older W3C spec (at https://www.w3.org/TR/cors/).

Comment: *Likewise with the Access-Control-Expose-Headers response header.* The `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header's place is in the response to the actual request, though; not in the response to the preflight request. See just above https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#http-access-control-expose-headers: _An HTTP response to a CORS request that is not a CORS-preflight request can also include an [`Access-Control-Expose-Headers`]_