# blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present, but it literally is. SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, cors

ok i'm quite sure you guys know this error so let's just skip on my solution and the reasons of it not working, I have an Interceptor which is basically a filter, where I did this:

```
@Component
public class AllRequestInterceptor implements HandlerInterceptor {
    
    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler)
            throws Exception {
        
        if(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("options")) {
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "*");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");
            response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");
        }
        
        for(String header: response.getHeaderNames()) {
            System.out.println(header);
        }
        
        return HandlerInterceptor.super.preHandle(request, response, handler);
    }
}
```

the CORS preflight request actually enters the if block, I get the headers printed afterwards and they're all present, and yet that party-pooper says otherwise, why does it say otherwise?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you are looking for, but this worked for me.

```
@Configuration
@Order(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class CorsInterceptor implements Filter{

    public CorsInterceptor() {
    }



    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest req, ServletResponse res, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) res;
        HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) req;
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Max-Age", "3600");
        response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*");

        if ("OPTIONS".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getMethod())) {
            response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
        } else {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) {
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
    }
}
```

Comment: yes, this works, don't know why tho the only difference is that you don't use wildcards and set the response status to ok, using interceptor i setted the status to 200 which should be the same thing but it kept not working, oh well guess I'll keep on using javax as if it's the 1700's  

Answer (score 0):

CORS must be sent on all requests, not just on OPTIONS: [CORS HEADERS present only on preflight or every request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24264574/cors-headers-present-only-on-preflight-or-every-request)

Simply remove `if(request.getMethod().equalsIgnoreCase("options"))` and its corresponding brackets, and it should work.

Comment: doesn't work and now the code doesn't even get executed, this cors thing hates me

Comment: Does it compile? If it does, check for relevant exceptions in your console; if it doesn't, try double-checking your syntax.

Comment: yes it compiles and the application starts, for some reason I had to open another session of browser, but even tho it gets executed without the if condition the outcome is the same

Comment: What exactly is the outcome? What are the request headers/body, and the response headers/body? Does it print the CORS header only in the OPTIONS request, or also in the other request? What method are you using? Does your browser block any request?

Comment: the headers of the preflight are those:
 host : localhost:8443
connection : keep-alive
accept : */*
 access-control-request-method : POST
access-control-request-headers : content-type
origin : http://127.0.0.1:4200
 user-agent : Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/103.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
sec-fetch-mode : cors
sec-fetch-site : cross-site sec-fetch-dest : empty
referer : http://127.0.0.1:4200/
accept-encoding : gzip, deflate, br
accept-language : it-IT,it;q=0.9

Comment: the reponse to the preflight has the headers shown into the code,idk about the bodies